# How can I get Python to plugin my password and Username for an .exe file it opened

Tags: python, passwords, os.system

Hey guys I'm new to programming and I would appreciate some help. My program can open an application I have but to enter the application it requires a password and username which I don't know how to make my program plug in automatically.

```
os.system('"C:\\abc\\123\\Filepath\\File.exe"')
```

After the code opens the program of the .exe file how do I make it to where it can than automatically plug in the username and password for the application.

Please and Thank you

Comment: When you run your application (.exe) from the terminal, can you pass it some input parameters? (something like `--username MY_USERNAME` and `--password MY_PASSWORD`). Maybe you can try to run it with the `-h` or `--help` option if you have no idea if the previous manipulation works. It could prompt you some usage information. If the program is not designed this way, it may be a bit more tricky to achieve your goal.

Comment: What is the file? You may need to use an api to access the parameters of the file programmatically.

Comment: the file is Oanda fxTradePractice Platform

Answer (score 2):

What you need is Pywinauto, which can make simple windows operations automatically. Please have a look at below Pywinauto website, there is an example to open Notepad and input "Hello World" automatically.
https://pywinauto.github.io/

I have another example to use Pywinauto to open putty application and connect to a remote Linux server, then input password to login, and run an Linux command.

```
from pywinauto.application import Application
import time

app = Application ().Start (cmd_line=u'putty -ssh user_name@10.70.15.175')
putty = app.PuTTY
putty.Wait ('ready')
time.sleep (1)
putty.TypeKeys ("password")
putty.TypeKeys ("{ENTER}")
time.sleep (1)
putty.TypeKeys ("ls")
putty.TypeKeys ("{ENTER}")
```

I use Python 2.7 and run the above Python code on Windows successfully.

You may need to install SWAPY (https://github.com/pywinauto/SWAPY) to get the Python code for automating your own "File.exe".

Comment: Ill try this out and I'm not sure if this changes anything but the file application is Oanda fxTradePractice application. Also the codes you wrote will they be in addition to the os.system or will I need to get rid of that code and add the one you recommended?

Comment: Open Word application and input HelloWorld 
`app = Application().Start(cmd_line=u'"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office 15\\root\\office15\\WINWORD.EXE" ')`
`opusapp = app.OpusApp`
`opusapp.Wait('ready')`
`time.sleep (2)`
`opusapp.TypeKeys("HelloWorld")`
This work in my windows environment. Because I don't have Oanda application, so I think you have to try by yourself.